# Unable to download full file using wget

Tags: downloads, file-sharing

I'm trying to download a file using wget. It shows the download is successful but doesn't gives me the right file. errors out when I try to untar the file. Also the downloaded file size is not correct nor consistent. Can you please let me know if I'm not using the wget properly?

This is what I tried:

```
root@Sys:~# wget http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/mahout/0.7/mahout-distribution-0.7.tar.gz
--2013-06-28 18:43:23--  http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/mahout/0.7/mahout-distribution-0.7.tar.gz
Resolving mirrors.sonic.net... 69.12.162.27
Connecting to mirrors.sonic.net|69.12.162.27|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 255 [text/html]
Saving to: `mahout-distribution-0.7.tar.gz'

100%[======================================>] 255         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-06-28 18:43:24 (20.5 MB/s) - `mahout-distribution-0.7.tar.gz' saved [255/255]
```

The actual file size is 70MB but it downloads only 20MB and says complete. If I try the same command again, it downloads a file with different size(Say 32MB).

Comment: It think this is not a valid download link. It returns an HTML page as you can see from the output in your question: `Length: 255 [text/html] Saving to: 'mahout-distribution-0.7.tar.gz'`. It's also just 255 bytes saved there - I don't see the 20-30MB you mentioned. Are you sure this is a valid link? Try opening the same link in the browser.

Comment: It's not downloading 20mb, it says it was dowloading with a **speed** of 20mb **per second**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely didn't download 20Mb but 255 bytes. 20mb is the download speed.

**cat** your file, `[text/html]` shows clearly that its not a compressed archive

```
$ cat mahout-distribution-0.7.tar.gz
```

you will find some information inside.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the reply. My bad, thats the speed. Sorry I was confused. But yeah, that link is a very valid link. I'm not sure why it doesnt download or throws any error.

Comment: did you find something useful in your file?  Use `cat` or any other way to display its content

Comment: Yes. I think the fire wall is blocking the file download as the size exceeded the specified limit. The downloaded file contains this error message within some xml tags. I have contacted my admin to download the file for me. Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: Facing the same issue. File was 15MB size but wget downloaded 4kb file.
Using cat I found websense was blocking the download,

`root@bd2ca13aa81d:/ivan# cat kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.tgz

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>NetScreen Web Filtering</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Websense has been set to block this site</BODY></HTML>`